# WebScraping Using Excel VBA on Mac

Tags: vba, macos, web-scraping

I am aware that there are several similar questions but no previous solution seems to work for me. I've tried existing macros, web querying, just about anything, and they've all failed so far.

I want to scrape currency exchange rate data from https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1 and get it into tabular form using VBA. My computer is macOS 10.14.16 Mojave and my version of Excel is Version 16.39.

I know that InternetExplorer objects will not work with my OS. I am also unable to create webqueries despite following steps to the tee.

Can anyone help me figure out a way to access the source for the website? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able get this data just now without much trouble using Excel on Windows.

- From the Menu: Data / From Web
- Enter the URL you provided above
- Select 'Table1' from the Navigator list
- Click "Load" at the bottom of the dialog

If this solution doesn't work for you, could you help us understand your constraints further?

Using "Record Macro" for these steps, I get the following macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Source{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""US Dollar"", type text}, {""1.00 USD"", type number}, {""inv. 1.00 USD"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 1"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```